# Java Class inheritance: can I make non static member in the parent class become static in the son?

Tags: java, inheritance

---

Before you start reading I would like to clarify:

I have already thought of other designs and work arounds
I'm only interested in the problem I exposed and not "changing" it (so no solutions such as delete the points in A and create new points fields in B and C...

---

lets consider the following code:

```
public class A {
    protected cpVect[][] points = null;
    ...
}
```

and its classes that inherits it:

```
    public class B extends A{

            ...
    }

    public class C extends A{

            ...
    }
```

so far so good.

my problem is that for B and C contains arrays of points that will be created in the constructor using something like

```
if(points == null){calculate points code}
```

the problem is as follow

points in A can't be static because the dimensions are different in B and C.

but every instance of B will share the B points and every instance of C will share the C points. (in other words a Square will always be a square and a triangle will always be a triangle). and therefore I want to have the B:points and C:points static so that i don't get duplicates of the values for every instance.

So is there a way to redefine points as static in B and C when it is not static in A?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, but don't want to make the accessors static, but you want to make the field static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access `points` solely through property methods (getters/setters) you can do whatever you want in the subclasses. If you use inheritance, `A` will have to be an abstract class. Otherwise you'd always carry around the empty points variable in `A` (losing 8 bytes, probably).

In this case the hierarchy would look like this:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public cpVect[][] getPoints();

    // more methods ...
}

public class B extends A {

    private final static cpVect[][] POINTS = calculatePoints();

    @Override
    public cpVect[][] getPoints() {
        return POINTS;
    }

    private cpVect[][] calculatePoints() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the same for `C`. If `A` includes no other state or functionality, you should make it an `interface`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the field static, but you could make it a singleton. You'll have multiple references to the singleton, but you'll only need one copy of each points array. For example, in B:

```
  class B extends A {
      private cpVect[][] B_points = null;

      public B() {
          if (B_points == null)
              B_points = create_B_points();
          points = B_points;
      }
  }
```

If multithreaded, you'll need to add synchronization.

(Sorry for earlier half-finished version. The SO editor seems quirky in Chrome).

Answer (score -1):

There is no significance of static and non-static in inheritance. ie if you have a member variable in a parent class then you can have the same name for the static member of the child class. as shown

```
class test {

 public int a;

}

class test1 extends test {
    public static int a;

}
```

And through objects you can access a of test.

through class test1 you can access static a of test1. as both are independent.

**You cannot have a same variable as the member in parent and static in child.**

Comment: -1 static does influence inheritance quite a bit, so your statement seems misleading.

Comment: @josefx, its subjected to his problem, not in general java ineritance.